# Spring security Role based HTTP request Authorization

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I am getting 403 forbidden on Deleting an item from the inventory as well as creating a new resource in the database and below is my configuration and the controller written by me.

**WebSecurityConfiguration Class:**

```
package com.inventoryservice.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.authorization.AuthorityAuthorizationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("test")
                .password("test_pass")
                .roles("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .withUser("store")
                .password("store_pass")
                .roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests()
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/items-management").hasRole("ADMIN")
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/items-management").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
                    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/items-management").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

**Inventory controller:**

It has all the endpoints being configured with the database records fetching from the services

```
package com.inventoryservice.controller;

import com.inventoryservice.dto.request.InventoryRequestDto;
import com.inventoryservice.dto.response.InventoryItemDto;
import com.inventoryservice.dto.response.InventoryResponseDto;
import com.inventoryservice.entity.Inventory;
import com.inventoryservice.service.ItemService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/items-management")
public class InventoryController {

    private ItemService itemService;

    @Autowired
    public InventoryController(ItemService itemService) {
        this.itemService = itemService;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<InventoryResponseDto> getItems() {
        return new ResponseEntity(
                InventoryResponseDto.builder()
                        .lines(itemService.getItems())
                        .build()
                , HttpStatus.OK
        );
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<InventoryResponseDto> create(@RequestBody InventoryRequestDto inventory) {
        return new ResponseEntity(
                InventoryResponseDto
                        .builder()
                        .lines(itemService.create(inventory.getLines()))
                        .build()
                , HttpStatus.CREATED
        );
    }

    @DeleteMapping
    public ResponseEntity delete(@RequestBody InventoryItemDto inventoryItemDto) {
        itemService.deleteItems(
                inventoryItemDto.getItemIds()
        );
        return ResponseEntity.ok(inventoryItemDto);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've encountered this issue because in Spring Security protection against Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) attack, which aims to trick the user to execute certain action in the application where they are authenticated, is enabled by default.

CSRF protection is meant to guard against undesirable mutating actions, therefore your POST-request fails. For more information on CSRF and when it's justifiable to disable CSRF protection, [refer to the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/features/exploits/csrf.html#csrf-when).

For now, just in order to test your end-points, you can disable CSRF like that:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .authorizeHttpRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/items-management").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/items-management").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","USER")
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/items-management").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .csrf().disable();   // <- add this line
}
```

Comment: I have added CSRF disable but still getting 403 Forbidden.

Comment: Do you have any other solutions? The one you told is not working.